# Why does my identicon in the ranking differ from my profile's identicon?

Tags: bug, identicon

I just realized that my identicon in the [ranking](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/2455604#2455604) page has a different color and pattern compared to that in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455604/marwie?tab=profile) page:

[image: identicon on ranking page]
[image: identicon on profile]

Looking at other users profiles didn't show any differences between their ranking and profile identicons. Is this a bug?

**Update**
It seems to be an issue with gravatar producing different icons depending on the size of the icon you demand. The hash is actually just the md5 sum of your registered email address.

[https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f61ab3aad5b972468c5dcd70213ef6b3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f61ab3aad5b972468c5dcd70213ef6b3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f61ab3aad5b972468c5dcd70213ef6b3?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/avatar-picture-problem

Comment: In short: Gravatar is bad. Upload a new picture using imgur hosting.

Comment: Oh my, good chance it's not Gravatar fault directly.  They're also using varnish, some crappy CDN provider. It needs tons of kicks to serve the proper images. It's causing bugs for SE own Sprites as well.